# Problemas con fn.call() dentro de un metodo en un objecto de Javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema con fn.call() dentro de un metodo en un objecto. Tengo un arreglo que internamente tiene objetos, los valores de estos objectos son tipo y genero.

```
    const gustos = [
    {tipo:'libros', genero: 'futuristas'},
    {tipo:'musica', genero: 'rap'}
]

class User{
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name
    }
    listarGustos(arr){
        length = arr.length
        console.log(arr)
        for(let i = 0; i <length; i++){    
        return function (i){
             console.log(`${this.tipo} : ${this.genero}`)
             console.log(i)
         }.call(arr[i])
        }
    }
}
const victor = new User("victor")

victor.listarGustos(gustos)
```

al hacer la sentencia de victor.listarGustos(gustos) solo me esta regresando 'libros : futuristas' es decir solo me esta regresando el primer valor de el array gustos. Alguna corrección que le deba hacer a mi codigo? gracias de antemano

Comment: Si te devuelve libros:futuristas. Devuelve dos arrays: libros: futuristas y música: rap, mas luego te devuelve de nuevo libros:futuristas                          `victor.listarGustos(gustos)
(2) [{…}, {…}]0: {tipo: "libros", genero: "futuristas"}1: {tipo: "musica", genero: "rap"}length: 2__proto__: Array(0)
 libros : futuristas
 undefined
undefined`

Comment: @MiguelEspeso exacto, sabes a que se debe esto?

Comment: @MiguelEspeso deberia dar como resultado los gustos del "usuario"

libros : futuristas
musica : rap

necesito utilizar la el metodo call() para practicar, no se si sea algun problema con el loop.

Comment: A ver si puedo ayudarte, he preguntado...

Comment: @MiguelEspeso ya esta resuelto, revisa mi respuesta.

Comment: Perfecto, si te sirve lo mio puedes utilizar y modificarlo a tu gusto

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78043/discussion-between-miguel-espeso-and-victor-lozada).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya resuelto.

```
const gustos = [
    {tipo:'libros', genero: 'futuristas'},
    {tipo:'musica', genero: 'rap'}
]

class User{
    constructor(name){
        this.name = name
    }
    listarGustos(arr){
        length = arr.length
        const print = function(i){
            console.log(`#${i + 1 } ${this.tipo} : ${this.genero}`)
        }
        // const print = (i) => console.log(`#${i + 1 } ${this.tipo} : ${this.genero}`)
        for(let i = 0; i < length; i++){
            print.call(arr[i], i)
        }
    }
}
const victor = new User("victor")

victor.listarGustos(gustos)
```

Answer (score 0):

Piensa que tan pronto como escriba return, el bucle for y la función actual se cerrarán inmediatamente. Puede usar un IIFE (Expresión de función invocada inmediatamente) y ajustar su parte de función de retorno de la siguiente manera que podría lograr lo que estás tratando de hacer:

```js
listarGustos(arr) {
  length = arr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   (function(i) {
    return function() {
     console.log(`${this.tipo} : ${this.genero}`);
    }.call(arr[i]);
   })(i);
  }
 }
```